# Browser extension to intervene parsing

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to intervene with browser's parsing mechanism possibly with a browser extension e.g. the browser retrieves some page from the internet, I let the browser to parse the DOM, but block executing the javascript even if it's in parallel thread mode (async or defer), I want to inject or delete some code in javascript depending on some information in it, then allow the browser to execute the new javascript.

Is it possible to do such thing on a browser? The important part is to block, wait and execute in the browser for me.

Comment: In Firefox you can modify the HTML contents of response directly before the parsing begins. Firefox also has a `beforescriptexecute` event that helps preventing script execution. In Chrome you don't have that luxury so you'll have to do a lot of pretty low-level stuff like getting page HTML with XHR, modifying, overwriting the page HTML using document.write, which in turn may require modifying the CSP header using webRequest API. Another approach is used by uBlock: set a restrictive CSP that blocks all scripts but that spams the console with errors - the cost of the more universal approach.

Comment: BTW in case all scripts you want to block are loaded remotely (i.e. from http/https URLs) the solution is trivial - block them with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest as described in the documentation.

Comment: many thanks for your both answers. I want this to run on any webpage and I don't consider inline scripts for now, so I think yes they are all external scripts which are loaded remotely. I was looking at this chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest, okay this will block the javascript, but how can I inject the code if there is no javascript. Or you are saying that the external javascript are declared in the html and just javascript is not executed? Then, this could be my solution.

Comment: You can inject DOM script elements (with inline code or external src) in your content script. And in your background page you can modify the page CSP header in chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived so that your scripts are allowed via `nonce`, for example.

Comment: I am able to block all of the javascript including inline scripts in a tab with catching the request with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest. Then I try to allow the javascript execution when chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted and there exists some headers I need, but the script is not executed in some websites. I don't know but I think Chrome already passes that javascript execution stage in rendering process and doesn't run it again. Any ideas to warn Chrome to wait for me to decide if javascript executable or rerun the javascript after I finish my job without refreshing the page?